# Is it wrong to use "...the access..." in this sentence?

Tags: articles

> Reducing stress levels in the general population can be done effectively by improving **THE/- access** to mental health care.

At times, I get confused as to whether I should use "the" or not, and grammar rules dictate that "the" can be used to describe specific things; hence, I feel "...the access to mental..." is grammatically correct. Am I right?

Most importantly, please give me tips on how to use "the". Though I have read about its use in some many online dictionaries, using it is still confusing.

Comment: You could say **their access** with the same meaning.

Answer (score 5):

Both are correct and have similar enough meanings that it probably makes no difference.

The difference comes from the word "the" adding the nuance of *specificity*.

Without "the", it simply means *access to mental health care* in general.

Using "the" indicates specifically the *access to mental health care*, perhaps in contrast with *access to health care* or *access to care* in general; or it indicates specifically our current method of accessing mental health care.

Since English style prefers shorter and simpler sentences, without "the" is preferred unless there's some reason the speaker wants to specify something in contrast to another case, or to the more general case.